# How to create local notifications?

Tags: ios

How can I set up local notifications so that at the time I set, my app generates a notification/alert with a customized message?

Answer (score 104):

Here is sample code for *LocalNotification* that worked for my project.

**Objective-C:**

This code block in `AppDelegate` file :

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
    {
        [launchOptions valueForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        return YES;
    }

    // This code block is invoked when application is in foreground (active-mode) 
 -(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification {

        UIAlertView *notificationAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Notification"    message:@"This local notification" 
        delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];

        [notificationAlert show];
       // NSLog(@"didReceiveLocalNotification");
    }
```

This code block in .m file of any `ViewController`:

```
-(IBAction)startLocalNotification {  // Bind this method to UIButton action
    NSLog(@"startLocalNotification");

    UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    notification.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:7];
    notification.alertBody = @"This is local notification!";
    notification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
    notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
    notification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 10;

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];    
}
```

The above code display an AlertView after time interval of 7 seconds when pressed on button that binds `startLocalNotification` If application is in background then it displays `BadgeNumber` as 10 and with default notification sound.

This code works fine for iOS 7.x and below but for *iOS 8 it will prompt following error* on console:

> Attempting to schedule a local notification  with an alert but haven't received permission from the user to display alerts

This means you need register for local notification. This can be achieved using:

```
if ([UIApplication instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]){

    [application registerUserNotificationSettings [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeAlert|UIUserNotificationTypeBadge|UIUserNotificationTypeSound categories:nil]];
}
```

You can also refer [blog](http://jayprakashdubey.blogspot.in/2015/09/create-local-notification-in-ios.html) for local notification.

**Swift:**

You `AppDelegate.swift` file should look like this:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {    
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    application.registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: UIUserNotificationType.Sound | UIUserNotificationType.Badge | UIUserNotificationType.Alert, categories: nil))

    return true
}
```

The swift file (say `ViewController.swift`) in which you want to create local notification should contain below code:

```
//MARK: - Button functions
func buttonIsPressed(sender: UIButton) {
    println("buttonIsPressed function called \(UIButton.description())")

    var localNotification = UILocalNotification()
    localNotification.fireDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 3)
    localNotification.alertBody = "This is local notification from Swift 2.0"
    localNotification.timeZone = NSTimeZone.localTimeZone()
    localNotification.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitMinute
    localNotification.userInfo = ["Important":"Data"];
    localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName
    localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 5
    localNotification.category = "Message"

    UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(localNotification)
}


//MARK: - viewDidLoad

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var objButton : UIButton!
    . . .

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        . . .

        objButton = UIButton.buttonWithType(.Custom) as? UIButton
        objButton.frame = CGRectMake(30, 100, 150, 40)
        objButton.setTitle("Click Me", forState: .Normal)
        objButton.setTitle("Button pressed", forState: .Highlighted)

        objButton.addTarget(self, action: "buttonIsPressed:", forControlEvents: .TouchDown)

        . . .
    }

    . . .
}
```

**The way you use to work with Local Notification in iOS 9 and below is completely different in iOS 10.**

Below screen grab from Apple release notes depicts this.

[image: Screenshot]

You can refer [apple reference document](https://developer.apple.com/reference/usernotifications) for UserNotification.

*Below is code for local notification:*

**Objective-C:**

1. In `App-delegate.h` file use `@import UserNotifications;`
2. App-delegate should conform to `UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate` protocol
3. In `didFinishLaunchingOptions` use below code:

   ```
   UNUserNotificationCenter *center = [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter];
   [center requestAuthorizationWithOptions:(UNAuthorizationOptionBadge | UNAuthorizationOptionSound | UNAuthorizationOptionAlert)
          completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error) {
                 if (!error) {
                     NSLog(@"request authorization succeeded!");
                     [self showAlert];
                 }
   }];

   -(void)showAlert {
       UIAlertController *objAlertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"show an alert!" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

       UIAlertAction *cancelAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK"
         style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
           NSLog(@"Ok clicked!");
       }];

       [objAlertController addAction:cancelAction];


       [[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] objectAtIndex:0] rootViewController] presentViewController:objAlertController animated:YES completion:^{            
       }];

   }
   ```
4. Now create a button in any view controller and in IBAction use below code :

   ```
   UNMutableNotificationContent *objNotificationContent = [[UNMutableNotificationContent alloc] init];

   objNotificationContent.title = [NSString localizedUserNotificationStringForKey:@“Notification!” arguments:nil];

   objNotificationContent.body = [NSString localizedUserNotificationStringForKey:@“This is local notification message!“arguments:nil];

   objNotificationContent.sound = [UNNotificationSound defaultSound];

   // 4. update application icon badge number
   objNotificationContent.badge = @([[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationIconBadgeNumber] + 1);

   // Deliver the notification in five seconds.
   UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger *trigger =  [UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger                                             triggerWithTimeInterval:10.f repeats:NO];       

   UNNotificationRequest *request = [UNNotificationRequest requestWithIdentifier:@“ten”                                                                            content:objNotificationContent trigger:trigger];

   // 3. schedule localNotification
   UNUserNotificationCenter *center = [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter];

   [center addNotificationRequest:request withCompletionHandler:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
       if (!error) {
           NSLog(@“Local Notification succeeded“);
       } else {
           NSLog(@“Local Notification failed“);
       }
   }];
   ```

**Swift 3:**

1. In `AppDelegate.swift` file use `import UserNotifications`
2. Appdelegate should conform to `UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate` protocol
3. In `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` use below code

   ```
   // Override point for customization after application launch.
   let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
   center.requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound]) { (granted, error) in
       // Enable or disable features based on authorization.
       if error != nil {
           print("Request authorization failed!")
       } else {
           print("Request authorization succeeded!")
           self.showAlert()
       }
   }


   func showAlert() {
       let objAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Request authorization succeeded", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

       objAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
       //self.presentViewController(objAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)

       UIApplication.shared().keyWindow?.rootViewController?.present(objAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
   }
   ```
4. Now create a button in any view controller and in IBAction use below code :

   ```
   let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
   content.title = NSString.localizedUserNotificationString(forKey: "Hello!", arguments: nil)
   content.body = NSString.localizedUserNotificationString(forKey: "Hello_message_body", arguments: nil)
   content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()
   content.categoryIdentifier = "notify-test"

   let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger.init(timeInterval: 5, repeats: false)
   let request = UNNotificationRequest.init(identifier: "notify-test", content: content, trigger: trigger)

   let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
   center.add(request)
   ```

Comment: Do I necessarily need to have the funcButtonIsPressed run upon a button press? What if I want the app to, by default, give that notification weekly, should I just add it to the initial VC's viewDidLoad?

Comment: Also, why does your AppDelegate.swift file have didFinishLaunchingWithOptions twice?

Comment: " import UserNotifications " import this in your ViewController

Comment: Nice example. Note, that it is not necessary that AppDelegate conforms to `UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate`, unless you want it to execute some notification logic. Furthermore, requesting authorisation or sending local notification can be done outside of app delegate, depending on the needs.

Answer (score 51):

In appdelegate.m file write the follwing code in applicationDidEnterBackground to get the local notification

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
   UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc]init];
   notification.repeatInterval = NSDayCalendarUnit;
   [notification setAlertBody:@"Hello world"];
   [notification setFireDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:1]];
   [notification setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone  defaultTimeZone]];
   [application setScheduledLocalNotifications:[NSArray arrayWithObject:notification]];
}
```

Comment: When you schedule just ONE notification using setScheduledLocalNotifications: is unnecessary.  There is 
scheduleLocalNotification method that takes one argument - notification to be scheduled. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/scheduleLocalNotification:

Answer (score 19):

Creating local notifications are pretty easy. Just follow these steps.

1. On viewDidLoad() function ask user for permission that your apps want to display notifications. For this we can use the following code.

   ```
   UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge], completionHandler: {didAllow, error in
   })
   ```
2. Then you can create a button, and then in the action function you can write the following code to display a notification.

   ```
   //creating the notification content
   let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()

   //adding title, subtitle, body and badge
   content.title = "Hey this is Simplified iOS"
   content.subtitle = "iOS Development is fun"
   content.body = "We are learning about iOS Local Notification"
   content.badge = 1

   //getting the notification trigger
   //it will be called after 5 seconds
   let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 5, repeats: false)

   //getting the notification request
   let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "SimplifiedIOSNotification", content: content, trigger: trigger)

   //adding the notification to notification center
   UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request, withCompletionHandler: nil)
   ```
3. Notification will be displayed, just click on home button after tapping the notification button. As when the application is in foreground the notification is not displayed. But if you are using iPhone X. You can display notification even when the app is in foreground. For this you just need to add a delegate called **UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate**

For more details visit this blog post: **[iOS Local Notification Tutorial](https://www.simplifiedios.net/ios-local-notification-tutorial/)**

Answer (score 17):

Updated with **Swift 5** Generally we use three type of Local Notifications

1. Simple Local Notification
2. Local Notification with Action
3. Local Notification with Content

Where you can send simple text notification or with action button and attachment.

Using UserNotifications package in your app, the following example 
Request for notification permission, prepare and send notification as per user action AppDelegate itself, and use view controller listing different type of local notification test.

**AppDelegate**

```
import UIKit
import UserNotifications

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

    let notificationCenter = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        //Confirm Delegete and request for permission
        notificationCenter.delegate = self
        let options: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .sound, .badge]
        notificationCenter.requestAuthorization(options: options) {
            (didAllow, error) in
            if !didAllow {
                print("User has declined notifications")
            }
        }

        return true
    }

    func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    }
    func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    }
    func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    }
    func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
    }
    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0
    }


    //MARK: Local Notification Methods Starts here

    //Prepare New Notificaion with deatils and trigger
    func scheduleNotification(notificationType: String) {

        //Compose New Notificaion
        let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        let categoryIdentifire = "Delete Notification Type"
        content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default
        content.body = "This is example how to send " + notificationType
        content.badge = 1
        content.categoryIdentifier = categoryIdentifire

        //Add attachment for Notification with more content
        if (notificationType == "Local Notification with Content")
        {
            let imageName = "Apple"
            guard let imageURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: imageName, withExtension: "png") else { return }
            let attachment = try! UNNotificationAttachment(identifier: imageName, url: imageURL, options: .none)
            content.attachments = [attachment]
        }

        let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 5, repeats: false)
        let identifier = "Local Notification"
        let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: identifier, content: content, trigger: trigger)

        notificationCenter.add(request) { (error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("Error \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }

        //Add Action button the Notification
        if (notificationType == "Local Notification with Action")
        {
            let snoozeAction = UNNotificationAction(identifier: "Snooze", title: "Snooze", options: [])
            let deleteAction = UNNotificationAction(identifier: "DeleteAction", title: "Delete", options: [.destructive])
            let category = UNNotificationCategory(identifier: categoryIdentifire,
                                                  actions: [snoozeAction, deleteAction],
                                                  intentIdentifiers: [],
                                                  options: [])
            notificationCenter.setNotificationCategories([category])
        }
    }

    //Handle Notification Center Delegate methods
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                willPresent notification: UNNotification,
                                withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
        completionHandler([.alert, .sound])
    }

    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                                withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        if response.notification.request.identifier == "Local Notification" {
            print("Handling notifications with the Local Notification Identifier")
        }
        completionHandler()
    }
}
```

and **ViewController**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    var appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate
    let notifications = ["Simple Local Notification",
                         "Local Notification with Action",
                         "Local Notification with Content",]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return notifications.count
    }

     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = notifications[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let notificationType = notifications[indexPath.row]
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "",
                                      message: "After 5 seconds " + notificationType + " will appear",
                                      preferredStyle: .alert)
        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Okay, I will wait", style: .default) { (action) in
            self.appDelegate?.scheduleNotification(notificationType: notificationType)
        }
        alert.addAction(okAction)
        present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Impressive! Good Tutorial

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
   UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc]init];
   notification.repeatInterval = NSDayCalendarUnit;
   [notification setAlertBody:@"Hello world"];
   [notification setFireDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:1]];
   [notification setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone  defaultTimeZone]];
   [application setScheduledLocalNotifications:[NSArray arrayWithObject:notification]];
}
```

This is worked, **but in iOS 8.0 and later**, your application must register for user notifications using `-[UIApplication registerUserNotificationSettings:]` before being able to schedule and present UILocalNotifications, do not forget this.

Comment: -[UIApplication registerUserNotificationSettings:]  will override push notification setting. so Take care if used push actionable notification.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)kundanselect
{
    NSMutableArray *allControllers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:self.navigationController.viewControllers];
    NSArray *allControllersCopy = [allControllers copy];
    if ([[allControllersCopy lastObject] isKindOfClass: [kundanViewController class]]) 
    {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]postNotificationName:@"kundanViewControllerHide"object:nil userInfo:nil];
    }
    else
    {
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:4 forKey:@"selected"];
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"kundansegue" sender:self];
    }
}
```

**`[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(ApparelsViewControllerHide) name:@"ApparelsViewControllerHide" object:nil];`**

Answer (score 0):

iOS 8 users and above, please include this in App delegate to make it work.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    if ([UIApplication instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)])
    {
        [application registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeAlert|UIUserNotificationTypeBadge|UIUserNotificationTypeSound categories:nil]];
    }

    return YES;
}
```

And then adding this lines of code would help,

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc]init];
    notification.repeatInterval = NSDayCalendarUnit;
    [notification setAlertBody:@"Hello world"];
    [notification setFireDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:1]];
    [notification setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone  defaultTimeZone]];
    [application setScheduledLocalNotifications:[NSArray arrayWithObject:notification]];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you have requested for authorisation and registered your app for notification.

Here is the code to create local notifications

```
@available(iOS 10.0, *)
    func send_Noti()
    {
        //Create content for your notification 
        let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        content.title = "Test"
        content.body = "This is to test triggering of notification"

        //Use it to define trigger condition
        var date = DateComponents()
        date.calendar = Calendar.current
        date.weekday = 5 //5 means Friday
        date.hour = 14 //Hour of the day
        date.minute = 10 //Minute at which it should be sent


        let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: date, repeats: true)
        let uuid = UUID().uuidString
        let req = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: uuid, content: content, trigger: trigger)

        let notificationCenter = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
        notificationCenter.add(req) { (error) in
            print(error)
        }
    }
```