# Reminder in iphone app

Tags: iphone

I am making small iphone application. In this application I have put 5 time picker to show different timings. Now I want to put reminders or alarms on these 5 particular time. I dont know how to use reminder or alarm functionality. If anyone know please help me.

thanks alot..

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6047117/how-to-create-local-notifications-in-iphone-app

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://iphonesdkdev.blogspot.com/2010/04/local-push-notification-sample-code-os.html) is a pretty decent tutorial on using local notifications.