# iOS Push Notifications without using a server

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification

How do you go about sending users push notifications for automated actions in an app, such as sending them a notification when their lives have been refilled?  This doesn't seem like an action that should need a server, but rather the app itself determines when to send out the notification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is not a push notification, but a local notification. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6047117/how-to-create-local-notifications-in-iphone-app)