# No sound on notification with soundName in iOS

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification, localnotification

i'm looking for work sound on notification with soundName in Objective-C on test project, but this doesn't work.

I used the code from [how to create local notifications in iphone app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6047117/how-to-create-local-notifications-in-iphone-app) answer, but sound don't work, i don't understant why :(.

In my ViewController.m

```
- (IBAction)startLocalNotification:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"startLocalNotification");

    UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    notification.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:5];
    notification.alertBody = @"This is local notification!";
    notification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
    notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
    notification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 10;

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];
}
```

And in my AppDelegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    if ([UIApplication instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]){

        [application registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings
                                                       settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeAlert|UIUserNotificationTypeBadge|
                                                       UIUserNotificationTypeSound categories:nil]];
    }

    [launchOptions valueForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];
    return YES;
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification {


    UIAlertView *notificationAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Notification"    message:@"This local notification"
                                                               delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];

    [notificationAlert show];
}
```

Comment: Can you post your code? And the error you are facing? It will help you getting answer

Comment: Edited. And I havn't error :/ Just sound doesn't work, notification are allowed and sounds too from simulator / iPhone.

Comment: So both the simulator and the device won't play a sound? Make sure on the device your ringer is on.

Answer (score 0):

make sure your app is in background so you can hear sound otherwise you cannot able to hear the sound.