# Local Notifications for before ending date in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, localnotification

I am creating one app in this I am giving start date and end date. I want to give local notifications for end date before one day. can you please help me for this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to create local notifications in iphone app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6047117/how-to-create-local-notifications-in-iphone-app)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). What have you already tried yourself to do this? This is not a coding-writing or tutoring service. Questions should show **evidence of research and attempts to solve the problem yourself**, a clear outline of your specific coding-related issue, and any relevant code in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so we have enough information to be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

You can subtract a number of days by calling the dateByAddingTimeInterval method on your end date.

Like so:

```
NSDate *endDate = [NSDate date];
NSDate *fireDate = [fireDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:-1*24*60*60];
```