# How to send notifications at a specified time with objective-c

Tags: iphone

I'm trying to send a Push Notification at a time, let's say 9:00 a.m. Also, what is the best way to do this, Objective C or Swift? I am relatively new to both languages so it doesn't really matter.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to create local notifications in iphone app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6047117/how-to-create-local-notifications-in-iphone-app)

Comment: use this code for scheduled your notification , you can use local notification as well as push notification for this functionality  https://github.com/ahmedabadie/Robin.

Comment: If your question is regarding local notifications (self-sent by application itself), it's a duplicate of the question linked by the4kman. If your question it regarding remote notifications (sent by a backend), then it's done server-side, by your server provider or a third-party service, and as such it's not done in ObjC or Swift.