# Notification in swift 4

Tags: ios, swift

I'm getting http response in the form of a json object in my iOS app. The json object looks like

```
{
    coupons =     {
        1 = "You have 20% off
    };
    latitude = "3.043";
    "location_address" = "Pico";
    "location_name" = Starbucks;
    longitude = "-18.421964";
}
```

Now I want to send this as notification on my app. How do I do it? Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: You want to send it from serverside ?

Comment: Yes! I'm getting this response from server side. But I want to show it on the app instead of printing in console of my xcode project

Comment: Please make it clear what task you trying to achieve, please provide more details.

Comment: I'm sending out my location from the app and receiving back this json object from my server if it's near a coffee shop. I want to show the result as a notification on the app.

Comment: you have to show local notification or you can also show alert

Comment: if your app is in foreground, show an alert, else use a local notification. see [this link](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/SchedulingandHandlingLocalNotifications.html)
and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22660122/7698092)

Comment: But my issue is how do I parse the json object I'm getting in the notification?

Answer (score 0):

by using userNotificatinCenterDelegate you can achieve it