# What is the Apple Maps navigation notification type?

Tags: ios, notifications

I am building an app that interacts with dangerous equipment. Because of this, I need to be able to alert them of various events when they are operating the app in the background. I am looking at the type of notification that Apple Maps uses to alert users that their turn is coming up. This is exactly what I want, but I can't find what type of notification it is or how to implement it.

I have tried push notifications, alerts, etc... None of them are what I am looking for.

[image: Apple Maps Notification]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notification type Apple Maps uses for turn-by-turn navigation is **not accessible to public APIs**. Other third-party navigation apps (such as Google Maps) use standard push notifications for that reason.

To mimic the look of the Apple Maps notification, use a [local notification](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6047117/3151675) with an attached `UNNotificationContentExtension`.