# Sync notifications across the iCloud devices

Tags: swift, xcode, icloud, cloudkit, usernotifications

Built-in iOS Reminders app allows us to create to-do lists with their own reminders (notifications). And all of the lists, and reminders are can easily sync across the iCloud devices.

Once synced the iCloud devices can easily send (location and calendar) notifications, while offline. Is it possible to create an app like the iOS Reminders (sync notifications)? I’m sorry, I haven’t any example (code) to share with you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your question is if you can sync notifications with iCloud. The answer is yes.

Here are couple considerations:

- Apple is more than likely syncing `Reminder` records over CloudKit. The "notifications" are probably attributes of a `Reminder` record with dates, times, and places saved along with them so they know when and where to show the notifications.
- To show notifications offline, you will use the data in each `Reminder` record to trigger them with `UNUserNotificationCenter`. How to do this is pretty well covered across multiple versions of Swift [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6047117/how-can-i-create-local-notifications-in-ios).

I hope that helps get you started. Good luck!

Comment: Don't you have to use silent push notifications to create local notifications across devices?

Comment: @rs7 Not yet, any suggestions?

Comment: When creating a local notification for current device, I create a CKRecord Reminder and I'm using CKSubscriptions to sync notifications across devices. You can pass the relevant info through the CKSubscription payload (such as date, identifier, title, message etc), and from that you can create a local notification for every other device inside didReceiveRemoteNotification. Hope this makes sense.